# Cant recognize live usb when booting

Tags: dual-boot, surface

Could somebody please help me with this? I have checked and double checked that secure boot is disable in the UEFI settings. No matter what i do, i cannot get my ubuntu live usb to be listed under the "use a device" menu when trying to boot from it. I have tried different usb drives and different programs to create the live usb. Could anyone please suggest any possible causes for this? Cheers!

Comment: Can you tell us what method you have tried to create the USB?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know if the same live USB would boot another machine. I doubt it would. I've had bad luck with unetbootin recently - I get exactly this result.

What I've found to work is `dd`, a Linux/Unix disk and data copying utility. The command is

```
dd if=<file-you-want-to-copy.iso> of=<usb-device-you-want-to-boot-from>
```

For example, if I had downloaded 13.04 to ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso in my home directory, I would enter

```
dd if=`/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you are using FAT file system and check in BIOS if you have enabled boot from USB option.